# Coloring button link background area when it's hovered

Tags: css, vaadin

I'm developing a web application using the Vaadin framework.

I have a Button styled as BaseTheme.BUTTON_LINK and have an icon showing. The button is assigned a CSS class which has a hover state, when the button is hovered i want to change the background of the button to white color.
When i expanded the area to be coloured with firebug, it gives this :

```
<div class="v-slot v-slot-link" style="width: 25%; margin-left: 0px;">
 <div class="v-button v-widget link v-button-link" tabindex="0" role="button">
  <span class="v-button-wrap">
  <img class="v-icon" alt="" src="http://localhost:8081/VaadinButtonPanel/APP/connector/42/277/icon/duke.png">
  <span class="v-button-caption">Click Me</span>
 </span>
</div>
</div>
```

So i wrote this in css style but it didn't work for me :

```
  .v-button-link  .v-slot .v-slot-link .v-button-caption:hover{
     color: #1b699f;
     background : #FFF;
    }
```

Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Take a close look at your selector. It doesn't match your html structure

```
.v-slot.v-slot-link .v-button-link .v-button-caption:hover
```

would be a working selector

Comment: No I am not as this is the same element with both classes (it is discussable if both classes are needed for the selector but I just rearranged the given one so that it matches)

Comment: I forgot the :hover, did you include that? Maybe you need an !important because some other style is more important than yours?

Answer (score 0):

```
.v-button-caption:hover{
 color: #1b699f;
 background : #FFF;
}
```

try this maybe it would work, it's working here [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/otCKs)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overcomplicating the CSS.

This should work:

```
.v-button-caption:hover{
     color: #1b699f;
     background : #FFF;
    }
```

Demo here:  http://jsbin.com/eyAxEti/1/edit